# Corrupted memory with Hello World with Pthreads

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I'm working through some simple pthread examples form llnl.computing.gov pthreads tutorial. The program on the website prints out the address of the threadid, but I would like to pass the address of the id to PrintHello, and then use dereference the address to get the id. I think with the sleep in there every thread should print 8 (the number of threads). The code is

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUM_THREADS  8

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long *taskid = (long *)threadid;
   sleep(1);
   printf("Hello from thread %ld\n", *taskid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc;
  long t;

  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++) {
    printf("Creating thread %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *) &t);
    if (rc) {
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
 }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When I compile and run this in Cygwin it seg faults with stack corruption errors. If I rewrite PrintHello as:

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
  long taskid = (long) threadid;
  sleep(1);
  printf("Hello from thread %ld\n", taskid);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

it doesn't seg fault, it just prints the address and I would like to dereference the address and get the value of t from main.

Does anyone have some pointers on how to accomplish that goal? I know I can pass `t` to `pthread_create` instead of `&t` but I want to do it this way for learning purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `pthread_exit(NULL)` from the main thread, it terminates that thread.  At that point, any local variables in the `main` function, including `t`, are destroyed and can no longer be used.

If the main thread exits before all of your worker threads are finished using `t` (via the pointer you pass to them via `pthread_create`), your program exhibits undefined behavior.

The program contains a race condition because the access of the variable `t` from the worker threads and the destruction of the variable `t` from the main thread are unsynchronized.  One way to fix this problem would be to have the main thread join with each of the worker threads (via `pthread_join`) before it exits.

Comment: That makes sense. It works if I pass the value `t` because then each thread has its own copy of `t` which doesn't die when `Main` does?

Comment: Right, when you pass something _by value_, you make a copy of it for the callee to use.  When you pass the pointer, the pointer itself is passed by value, but the thing pointed to is the same in both the caller and the callee.

Comment: Even if you sync them - it won't do what you probably intended. All of the threads might print the same number, since they use the same variable. The values printed will depend on the scheduling

Answer (score 4):

1) you pass the *address* of `t` so every thread will get a pointer to the same variable, that's not the thread ID, it's a `long` which has a value that keeps changing.  You are modifying the variable in `main` and reading it in each other thread, which is a data race.

2) Probably what happens is that by the time the new threads execute the loop in `main` has finished and the variable has gone out of scope. When `main` exits its local variables will be popped off the stack, so when the other threads access `t` it is no longer on the stack. You don't have any synchronisation in your program to prevent that, so you have another data race there. You need to wait in `main` for the threads to finish, which you can do by calling `pthread_join` to wait for each one, but that still won't change the fact the other threads are trying to read a variable while it's being written to by another thread.

3) There's no need to call `pthread_exit` there, returning from the function or from main automatically exits the thread (just like calling `exit(0)` causes `main()` to finish)

Comment: Btw: doesn't the termination of the main thread stops all other threads?

Comment: @H2CO3, I believe calling `pthread_exit` doesn't terminate the entire process if other threads are still running. Calling `exit` or returning from `main` would cause the entire process to stop, even if other threads are running, but when `pthread_exit` is called the process only exits if it's the last thread.  Although  `pthread_exit` in main doesn't kill the whole process the variable `t` still goes out of scope and is popped off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers? Well, you have plenty of them in your thread functions...

The problem: you can't safely pass around the address of your local variable - it gets out of scope when main exits. You'll need to either declare the pointer as a static global variable, or malloc() sizeof(long) bytes of memory and use that.